# Google Oauth 2.0 minimum user interaction

Tags: java, google-api, authorization, google-oauth, oauth-2.0

We have a requriement, our users want to interact with various Google API's and therefore we require OAuth2.0 authorisation against Google's Authorisation Server.

Our constraint is that we are using a single web page front end and DO NOT want to redirect away from our page in order to obtain user authorisation.

In the ideal scenario, the user would check a box or click a button on our webpage, then using this input, we would receive access tokens and refresh tokens without the user interacting directly with a Google. Would such a idea be possible or is some form of user interaction a must in the intial step.

We have read some references to piggybacking with Oauth2.0 and OpenConnectId, we are however unsure about the applicability to such a scenario. Any advice or input would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to authenticate to google then you are going to have to show the authentication web page.  There is no way around that.  Once you have auth save the refresh token and you wont need to ask for access again.

Comment: We figured that, more hoping than anything, thanks for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need the flow of Refresh Token of OAuth2.

**Refresh Token of OAuth2:**

A refresh token is a string representing the authorization granted to
the client by the resource owner.  The string is usually opaque to
the client.  The token denotes an identifier used to retrieve the
authorization information.  Unlike access tokens, refresh tokens are
intended for use only with authorization servers and are never sent
to resource servers.

```
  +--------+                                           +---------------+
  |        |--(A)------- Authorization Grant --------->|               |
  |        |                                           |               |
  |        |<-(B)----------- Access Token -------------|               |
  |        |               & Refresh Token             |               |
  |        |                                           |               |
  |        |                            +----------+   |               |
  |        |--(C)---- Access Token ---->|          |   |               |
  |        |                            |          |   |               |
  |        |<-(D)- Protected Resource --| Resource |   | Authorization |
  | Client |                            |  Server  |   |     Server    |
  |        |--(E)---- Access Token ---->|          |   |               |
  |        |                            |          |   |               |
  |        |<-(F)- Invalid Token Error -|          |   |               |
  |        |                            +----------+   |               |
  |        |                                           |               |
  |        |--(G)----------- Refresh Token ----------->|               |
  |        |                                           |               |
  |        |<-(H)----------- Access Token -------------|               |
  +--------+           & Optional Refresh Token        +---------------+

           Figure: Refreshing an Expired Access Token
```

The flow illustrated in Figure 2 includes the following steps:

(A)  The client requests an access token by authenticating with the
authorization server and presenting an authorization grant.

(B)  The authorization server authenticates the client and validates
the authorization grant, and if valid, issues an access token
and a refresh token.

(C)  The client makes a protected resource request to the resource
server by presenting the access token.

(D)  The resource server validates the access token, and if valid,
serves the request.

(E)  Steps (C) and (D) repeat until the access token expires.  If the
client knows the access token expired, it skips to step (G);
otherwise, it makes another protected resource request.

(F)  Since the access token is invalid, the resource server returns
an invalid token error.

(G)  The client requests a new access token by authenticating with
the authorization server and presenting the refresh token.  The
client authentication requirements are based on the client type
and on the authorization server policies.

(H)  The authorization server authenticates the client and validates
the refresh token, and if valid, issues a new access token (and,
optionally, a new refresh token).

[Resource Refs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1)

According to you scenery, you might try to use Ajax Call to fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Do you mean along the lines of: hidden div that is only populated and show when a redirect url is received, and displaying the webpage there?